# vagrant debian/buster64 box failed (win10)

Tags: vagrant, debian-buster

i try to setup vagrant 'debian/buster64' manually on win10 but got failure... my steps:

1. download box file from  https://vagrantcloud.com/debian/boxes/buster64/versions/10.4.0/providers/virtualbox.box
2. try to setup...

```
$ vagrant box add --name 'debian/buster64' '4d7865da-6242-4853-bc6c-807a63c734e6'
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'debian/buster64' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://D:/Downloads/4d7865da-6242-4853-bc6c-807a63c734e6
    box:
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and that enough disk space
is available and then try again.
The output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

x ./metadata.json: Cannot extract through symlink \\\\?\\C:\\Users\\mat\\.vagrant.d
x ./box.ovf: Cannot extract through symlink \\\\?\\C:\\Users\\mat\\.vagrant.d
x ./buster.vmdk: Cannot extract through symlink \\\\?\\C:\\Users\\mat\\.vagrant.d
x ./Vagrantfile: Cannot extract through symlink \\\\?\\C:\\Users\\mat\\.vagrant.d
bsdtar.EXE: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

```
os: windows 10
version: 1909
build: 18363.900
vagrant 2.2.9
```

Who knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have created a Windows Junction to redirect your user profile to another drive (as did I). Well, Vagrant does not like that at all.

Luckily, you can explicitly set the base config directory (`.vagrant.d`) for your Vagrant installation via the environment variable `VAGRANT_HOME`. Assuming you moved your profile to drive D, you should set the environment variable as follows:

```
VAGRANT_HOME=D:\Users\mat\.vagrant.d
```